# CalendarView and onSelectedDayChange method

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I've got a CalendarView which opens an AlertDialog when you select a day thanks to this piece of code :

```
calendar = (CalendarView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
                  // create the AlertDialog 
            }
}
```

It works perfectly. The only thing is that, when I scroll the calendar to change the month, the method above is called. Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?